# retrieve data from a dynamic website

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I would like to retrieve the database of a website in which data is accessed by selecting a date in a form. By pressing "OK", the application launches and a list (the data that interest me) is displayed

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a common task of `data scraping` all of major languages have APIEs to support data scrapping from various sites.

I suggest you should look for a suitable scraping tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate over all dates, parse response and build your own database based on information retrieved from this site.